# Creating reflections in actionscript using bitmap data

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection, bitmapdata

Can anyone point me to demos or source code for creating reflections in actionscript?
I want to create the effect of an object sitting on a reflective surface.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could use the following Reflection class:
http://code.google.com/p/daleyjem/source/browse/trunk/com/daleyjem/as3/Reflection.as

It also allows for "updating" the reflection on any given DisplayObect in the event you want to reflect a video (errors on streaming video due to security restrictions).